# React Only Showing One Piece Of Data From Collection On Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to pull a collection of users from FireStore in react with an async function. The code is only pulling one user when I want all users from the collection.

I am new to react and firestore and not sure what I am doing wrong. I have looked through firestore documentation, yet I have been unable to resolve issue.

Thank you for any help!

```
function Pull() {

    const [blogs,setBlogs]=useState([])
  
    const fetchBlogs=async()=>{
  
      const response=firestore.collection('user');
  
      const data= await response.get();
  
      data.docs.forEach(item=>{
      setBlogs([blogs,item.data()])
        console.log(data)
  
      })
  
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
  
      fetchBlogs();
  
    }, [])
  
    return (
  
      <div className="App">
  
        {
            blogs.map((items)=>
            <div className="blog-container">
                <h4>{items.user}</h4>
                
              </div>
            )
        }
            
  
          
  
        
  
      </div>
  
    );
  
  }
  
  
  export default Pull;
```

Comment: Instead of `forEach` loop, can you try: `setBlogs(data.docs.map(d => d.data()))` ?

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I am now trying to understand how that pulled all values from collection. Thank you again!

Comment: The `data` had all your documents. Ideally you should map an array and then set in state. Also `setBlogs([...blogs,item.data()])` The spread operator (`...`) is required when adding elements to array that way.